# Rails routing problems separating actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm learning about routing (it's quite confusing) and I have a controller called `drawings`, with an action called `add_e_drawing`.

My link looks like:

```
<li><%= link_to 'New E Drawing', main_app.new_e_drawing_path %></li>
```

and my route looks like:

```
 get '/drawings/new', to: 'drawings#new_e_drawing', as: 'new_e_drawing'
```

which is basically a standard 'new' action that has been modified to be prepopulated differently than the normal 'new' action.

If I place this below `resources :drawings`, it never takes effect, and the normal drawings/new action takes place.  If I place it before the resources phrase, then it works, but it also overrides my normal drawings#new action.

What is the correct way to set up this route?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to define both routes separately as follows:

```
  match '/drawings/new', to: 'drawings#new', as: 'new_drawing'
  match '/drawings/newe', to: 'drawings#new_e_drawing', as: 'new_e_drawing'
```